# I am using react and unable to install firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, npm

```
$ npm i firebase
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0","karma-coverage-is'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-01T04_59_26_404Z-debug.log
```

Please help me,  If you know the solution

Answer (score 0):

Please clean the cache and try again

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install --save firebase
```

Comment: `npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...\npBDRqjg8oL9IdnKZpE7'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-02T05_00_16_378Z-debug.log


`

Comment: Please open Windows Powershell as administrator and try the above two commands again.

Comment: `npm install --save firebase
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-w1plr2jYvzBkx/rHE6A0EJf9318ufA5omShLuGocPlQtrvphel+KJcd+R02outE5E2lSDhyM0l3EoiA0YCD4hA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-w1plr2jYvzBkx/rHE6A0EJf9318ufA5omShLuGocPlQtrvphel+KJcd+R02outE5E2lSDhyM0l3EoiA0YCD4hA== but got sha512-1znI2ZWBGAdXSYNAacUVZ18ahPNIUSEq8HnALlybmDM7zq48gOTP0Nz7bNj68UARsUei9LMgK8p1v0sGzS3IYQ==. (1477065 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-02T11_24_41_696Z-debug.log`

Comment: Please try the following 2 commands:.  . $ rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules $ npm install to try fixing the integrity error first